# haproxy-ingress multiple backend rules

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, haproxy-ingress

I am trying to play with multiple rules on one of my ingress statements:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/balance-algorithm: roundrobin
    ingress.kubernetes.io/maxconn-server: "10"
    #ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-verify-ca-secret: "tls-secret-portal"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: ingress-test
  namespace: testing
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my.domain.name
    secretName: tls-secret-portal
  rules:
   - host: my.domain.name
     http:
       paths:
         - path: /
           backend:
             serviceName: nginx-service
             servicePort: 8080
         - path: /link
           backend:
             serviceName: apache-service
             servicePort: 8080
```

Only the nginx-service at / will work.  If i swap the paths then only the apache-service will work.  If I give them both a path (/link1 and /link2), neither work and I get a 404 not found, the error on the one that does not work is always 404 not found. The certificate works fine and it is not a certificate issue.

Sean

Comment: do you have a `/link` path in the `apache-service`? the uri is copied verbatim to the backend unless you use a rewrite, doc [here](https://haproxy-ingress.github.io/docs/configuration/keys/#rewrite-target).

Comment: no there is not, i tried a rewrite rule, ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /, however the app is hard coded to  my.domain.name/ , so the page with /link comes up with rewrite rule, however any link will fail as it strips the /link.  Is there a variable for the target in the rewrite rule for the path?  Or a full on reverse proxy?

Comment: You wrote: "the app is hard coded to my.domain.name/, so the page with /link comes up with rewrite rule, however any link will fail as it strips the /link." - I am not sure I understand what you mean by that. Can you be more specific?

Comment: If i go to my.domain.name/link the page displays, but if i click a link on the application hosted there to say /admin instead of going to my.domain.name/link/admin it will simply go to my.domain.name/admin.  I know how to solve this using an external reverse proxy, just trying to learn haproxy-ingress (this is just me learning haproxy-ingress not a real production thing).

Comment: Rewriting your application is the cleanest way of doing it so I'd suggest you doing that. You can't just rewrite the response content from server and change urls/paths in flight. Well you could in theory but this is not a good idea. If you have come up with any other solutions, please share it, I woulds be happy to see it and hopefully learn sth. @SeanIffland

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your application is the cleanest way of doing it so I'd suggest you doing that.

You can't just rewrite the response content from server and change urls/paths in flight. It's easier said than done. You could try in theory but generally this is not a good idea.